# Fine-grained event handling with D3 brushes

Tags: javascript, events, svg, d3.js

I have a scatter plot that is generated using D3. Points (SVG circles) on the plot can be selected by clicking on them and regions can be selected using a D3 brush.

To ensure the circles get the click event I need to create the brush first so the circles are above it. Unfortunately this means I can't drag to create the brush extent when my cursor is over a point in the plot.

Is there a way to pass hover and click events to the circles, but handle drag related events with the brush?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It can be accomplished but with [use of the D3 brush API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#wiki-brush_extent) (See note below).

This is an example http://bl.ocks.org/4747894 where:

1. The `brush` element is *behind* the circles
2. The circles respond to the `mousedown` event. (Can respond to other events as well.)
3. The `brush` element is well-behaved even if dragging starts from inside one of the circles.

Some tracing and a look at the [D3 source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/brush.js#L107) suggests that the `extent` is not being reset properly when a `mousemove` event is fired from a `circle` element atop the brush. That can be fixed by resetting the `extent` for the brush in the `mousedown` listener for the `circle` elements:

```js
        circles.on("mousedown", function (d, i) {
            // _svg_ is the node on which the brush has been created
            // x is the x-scale, y is the y-scale
            var xy = d3.mouse(svg.node()),
                xInv = x.invert(xy[0]),
                yInv = y.invert(xy[1]);

            // Reset brush's extent
            brush.extent([[xInv, yInv], [xInv, yInv]]);

            // Do other stuff which we wanted to do in this listener
        });
```

---

**Note:** [As per the API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#wiki-brush_extent), the brush's selection **will not be refreshed** automatically on calling `.extent(values)`. Merely clicking on a circle will reset the `extent` but will not redraw the selection made. The selection will be discarded only when a different selection is started inside the `circle`, or by clicking outside the circles and the current selection. *This is the desired behavior, as I understand from the question*. However, this might break code which is written with the assumption that whatever is the `extent` of the brush would be the selection visible on the graph.

Comment: This is very close. Ideally, I'd like to be able to drag the brush around after it is created, even if I start on a circle, but it is a huge step up on how it's working now!

Comment: Indeed, I see that dragging a selection from inside a `<circle>` is still not possible. I will think about how to do it cleanly, though I suspect that doing a clean event passing would involve a patch for d3.

Answer (score 6):

Use `selection.on`: http://jsfiddle.net/NH6zD/1

```
var target,
    dimensions = {width: 200, height: 200},
    svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr(dimensions),
    rect = svg.append("rect").attr(dimensions); // Must be beneath circles 
svg
  .on("mousedown", function() {
      target = d3.event.target || d3.event.srcElement;
      if ( target === rect.node() ) {
          /* Brush */
      } else {
          /* Circle */
      }
  })
  .on("mousemove", function() {
      if (!target) return;
      if ( target === svg.rect() ) {
          /* Brush */
      } else {
          var mouse = d3.mouse(svg.node());
          target.attr({x: mouse[0], y: mouse[1]});
      }
  });
(function(exit) {
    for (var i in exit) svg.on(exit[i], function() { target = undefined; });
})(["mouseout", "mouseup"]);
```