# Drawing a selection in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I'm working on an angular app which allow user to create shapes and pictures in a main layout like he would do in PowerPoint for example. these shapes are mainly divs and spans that user can drag and drop.
My questions are:
1. how can I allow my user to make a selection of several shapes like in powerpoint (the blue selection in powerpoint) ?
2. what is the best way to allow user to resize shapes like in PowerPoint ?

I think that a good way will be to write an angular directive but I'm not sure about tools that I must use (jquery-ui, d3, ...)

**adding edit :**

What about using canvas ? Would it be a better option ? (each shape will be a little canva inserted in the main layout which will be a div. Is using a directive to fill the canva would be a good option ?

thanks

Comment: I would bet on D3. I only played with it a bit but looks very promissing. http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049330/is-d3-a-good-choice-for-building-a-free-form-diagram-editor