# d3: brush changes click to mouseover

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, click, brush

I'm trying to create a scatter plot with a combination of brush selection, tooltips and click events, but it seems that once I add a brush to an svg canvas, all click events on objects get mapped to mouseovers. Is there any way around this? Example code below and @ http://jsfiddle.net/7j8cr/

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>

var my_circles = [{"x": 40, "y": 100, "r": 12},
              {"x": 100, "y": 40, "r": 8}],
    width = 400,
    height = 400,
    svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

function click(d) { console.log("Clicky Clicky!") };
function mouseover(d) { console.log("I saw  mouse!") }

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, width]))
    .y(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, height]))

svg.call(brush);

svg.selectAll("dataObj")
    .data(my_circles)
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r })
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y })
        .style("fill", "blue")
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("click", click); 

</script>
```

Clicking on the circles triggers `mouseover()`, and you can get the same action to trigger the correct event by commenting out the line

```
svg.call(brush);
```

But then obviously you loose the brush.... is there a way to get all 3 acting correctly?

Comment: This [gist](http://bl.ocks.org/musically-ut/4747894) looks helpful, and so does this [blog post](http://wrobstory.github.io/2013/11/D3-brush-and-tooltip.html). The gist is mentioned by its author in this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697495/fine-grained-event-handling-with-d3-brushes).

Comment: Cool gist. That will probably help me tackle any remaining issues I have. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The click events are not getting translated to mousover, they are simply not happening -- the mouseover event you see is when you move the cursor over the circle to click it. The problem has an easy solution however -- all you need to do is set `pointer-events` to `all` on the circles.

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7j8cr/2/).

Comment: Awesome thanks! That totally works, however, there is certainly some mapping or something going on. In the origional version, clicks do cause the mouseover function to fire, and can continue to do so as many times as you click. Try it yourself. Now maybe it is the mouse disappearing and the reappearing or the events getting mapped? But it certainly happens, and doesn't happen when there is no brush, or pointer-events are set to all.

Comment: Doesn't happen here (I've tried several times) with Chrome.

Comment: huh, happened both on my work Mac with Chrome and my home PC with Firefox... Oh well, problem solved regardless.

Edit: just for useless detail. Nothing is fired on the first click, but all subsequent clicks spawn mouseover events. Truly bizarre.

Comment: The example fiddle brush behaves strangely. Starting the brush on the background selects normally but starting the brush by clicking on one of the circles results in the brush selection area being translated away from the mouse pointer. Thoughts?

Comment: When the circles received pointer events, you're not supposed to start the brush there as it will result in things like you've mentioned.