# d3.on("mouseover") occurring before mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onmouseover

This is a d3 bar chart. line 162 ,

```
.on("mouseover", console.log("I am on it"))
```

should only happen when user is over a bar on the bar chart, but the log is output from the time the page loads.

The running code is here, https://shanegibney.github.io/d3Mouseover/

The full code is here, https://github.com/shanegibney/d3Mouseover

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: avenir next, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .zoom {
            cursor: move;
            fill: none;
            pointer-events: all;
        }

        .axis {
            stroke-width: 0.5px;
            stroke: #888;
            font: 10px avenir next, sans-serif;
        }

        .axis>path {
            stroke: #888;
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <div id="totalDistance">
        </div>
    </body>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        /* Adapted from: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172 */

        var margin = {
                top: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 90,
                left: 50
            },
            margin2 = {
                top: 230,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 30,
                left: 50
            },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
            height2 = 300 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

        var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M");

        var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
            x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
            y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
            y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]),
            dur = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 12]);

        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0),
            xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2).tickSize(0),
            yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0);

        var brush = d3.brushX()
            .extent([
                [0, 0],
                [width, height2]
            ])
            .on("start brush end", brushed);

        var zoom = d3.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
            .translateExtent([
                [0, 0],
                [width, height]
            ])
            .extent([
                [0, 0],
                [width, height]
            ])
            .on("zoom", zoomed);

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        var focus = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "focus")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var context = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "context")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

        d3.json("dataDefault.json", function(error, data) {
            if (error) throw error;

            var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M");
            var mouseoverTime = d3.timeFormat("%a %e %b %Y %H:%M");
            var minTime = d3.timeFormat("%b%e, %Y");
            var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%b %Y");

            data.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.mouseoverDisplay = parseTime(d.date);
                    d.date = parseTime(d.date);
                    d.end = parseTime(d.end);
                    d.duration = ((d.end - d.date) / (60 * 1000)); // session duration in minutes
                    d.distance = +d.distance;
                    d.intensityInverted = (1 / (d.distance / d.duration)); // inverse of intensity so that the light colour is for low intensity and dark colour is for high intensity
                    d.intensity = Math.round(d.distance / d.duration); // actually intensity, metres per minute.
                    d.course = d.course.toLowerCase();
                    return d;
                },
                function(error, data) {
                    if (error) throw error;
                });

            var total = 0;

            data.forEach(function(d) {
                total = d.distance + total;
            });

            var minDate = d3.min(data, function(d) {
                return d.date;
            });

            total = String(total).replace(/(.)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,') //place thousands comma in total distance string

            var xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) {
                return d.date;
            });

            var yMax = Math.max(20, d3.max(data, function(d) {
                return d.distance;
            }));

            dur.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
                return d.duration;
            })]);

            var colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateInferno)
                .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
                    return d.intensityInverted;
                })]);

            var totalDistance = d3.select("#totalDistance").append("p").text("Total distance: " + total + "m");

            x.domain([xMin, new Date()]);
            y.domain([0, yMax]);
            x2.domain(x.domain());
            y2.domain(y.domain());

            // append scatter plot to main chart area
            var messages = focus.append("g");
            messages.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
            messages.selectAll("message")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return colorScale(d.intensityInverted);
                })
                .attr("class", "message")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return x(d.date);
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return y(d.distance);
                })
                .attr("width", function(d) {
                    return dur(d.duration);
                })
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return height - y(d.distance);
                })
        // .on("mouseover", onit);
        .on("mouseover", () => console.log("I am now on it for sure!"));

    // function onit(d) {
    //     console.log("I am on it now!")
    // }

            focus.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis x-axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            focus.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
                .call(yAxis);

            // Summary Stats
            focus.append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
                .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
                .attr("dy", "1em")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text("Distance in meters");

            // focus.append("text")
            //     .attr("x", width - margin.right)
            //     .attr("dy", "1em")
            //     .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            //     // .text("Messages: " + num_messages(data, x));
            //     .text("Total distance: " + total + "m");

            svg.append("text")
                .attr("transform",
                    "translate(" + ((width + margin.right + margin.left) / 2) + " ," +
                    (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + ")")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text("Date");

            svg.append("rect")
                .attr("class", "zoom")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
                .call(zoom);

            // append scatter plot to brush chart area
            var messages = context.append("g");
            messages.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
            messages.selectAll("message")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return colorScale(d.intensityInverted);
                })
                .attr("class", "message")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return x2(d.date);
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return y2(d.distance);
                })
                .attr("width", function(d) {
                    return dur(d.duration);
                })
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return height2 - y2(d.distance);
                });

            context.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis x-axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
                .call(xAxis2);

            context.append("g")
                .attr("class", "brush")
                .call(brush)
                .call(brush.move, x.range());

        });

        //create brush function redraw scatterplot with selection
        function brushed() {
            if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
            var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
            x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
            focus.selectAll(".message")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return x(d.date);
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return y(d.distance);
                })
                .attr("width", function(d) {
                    return dur(d.duration);
                })
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return height - y(d.distance);
                });

            focus.select(".x-axis").call(xAxis);
            svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
                .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
                .translate(-s[0], 0));
            var e = d3.event.selection;
            var selectedMessages = focus.selectAll('.message').filter(function() {
                var xValue = this.getAttribute('x');
                return e[0] <= xValue && xValue <= e[1];
            });
            // console.log(selectedMessages.nodes().length);
        }

        function zoomed() {
            if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
            var t = d3.event.transform;
            x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
            focus.selectAll(".message")
                // .enter().append("rect")
                // .style("fill", function(d) {
                //     return colorScale(d.intensityInverted);
                // })
                // .attr("class", "message")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return x(d.date);
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return y(d.distance);
                })
                .attr("width", function(d) {
                    return dur(d.duration);
                })
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return height - y(d.distance);
                });

            focus.select(".x-axis").call(xAxis);
            context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
        }

        function handleMouseOver(d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .style("fill", "lightBlue");
            g.select('text')
                .attr("x", 15)
                .attr("y", 5)
                .text("Session no. " + d.number)
                .append('tspan')
                .text("Date: " + mouseoverTime(d.mouseoverDisplay))
                .attr("x", 15)
                .attr("y", 30)
                .append('tspan')
                .text("Distance: " + d.distance + "m")
                .attr("x", 15)
                .attr("y", 50)
                .append('tspan')
                .text("Duration: " + d.duration + " mins")
                .attr("x", 15)
                .attr("y", 70)
                .append('tspan')
                .text("Intensity: " + d.intensity + " meters/mins")
                .attr("x", 15)
                .attr("y", 90)
                .append('tspan')
                .text("Pool: " + d.pool + "  (" + d.course + ")")
                .attr("x", 15)
                .attr("y", 110);
            console.log("handleMouseOver function");
        }

        function handleMouseOut(d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return colorScale(d.intensityInverted);
                });
            g.select('text').text("Total distance since " + minTime(minDate) + ": " + total + "m");
        }
    </script>
```

Sample data,

```
[{
        "number": "1",
        "date": "2016-11-09 11:15",
        "end": "2016-11-09 11:45",
        "distance": "1100",
        "course": "LC",
        "pool": "UCD"
    },
    {
        "number": "2",
        "date": "2016-11-10 10:40",
        "end": "2016-11-10 11:20",
        "distance": "1500",
        "course": "LC",
        "pool": "UCD"
    },

    {
        "number": "3",
        "date": "2016-11-11 16:45",
        "end": "2016-11-11 17:50",
        "distance": "2000",
        "course": "LC",
        "pool": "UCD"
    },
    {
        "number": "4",
        "date": "2016-11-12 12:48",
        "end": "2016-11-12 13:53",
        "distance": "2500",
        "course": "LC",
        "pool": "UCD"
    }
]
```

I added the last two lines here, but still no luck,

```
var messages = focus.append("g");
messages.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
messages.selectAll("message")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return colorScale(d.intensityInverted);
    })
    .attr("class", "message")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.distance);
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
        return dur(d.duration);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.distance);
    })
    // .on("mouseover", onit);
    .on("mouseover", () => console.log("I am now on it for sure!"));
    // function onit(d) {
    //     console.log("I am on it now!")
    // }
```

I suspect the problem is because I am using brushX() and zoom.

Comment: Possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527525/d3-brush-changes-click-to-mouseover?rq=1

Comment: The running code is here, https://shanegibney.github.io/d3Mouseover/

Comment: The code is here https://github.com/shanegibney/d3Mouseover

Answer (score 6):

When you do this:

```
.on("mouseover", console.log("I am on it"))
```

You're passing the **result** of the `console.log` function to the callback. Instead of that, you want to pass its **reference**:

```
.on("mouseover", function(){
    console.log("I am on it")
})
```

Check this snippet (don't hover over the circle!):

```js
var circle = d3.select("circle");
circle.on("mouseover", console.log("I'm on it!"));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="15" fill="teal"></circle>
</svg>
```

Now the same code, with the **reference** to `console.log`:

```js
var circle = d3.select("circle");
circle.on("mouseover", () => console.log("I'm on it!"));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="15" fill="teal"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks but "I'm on it!" is always in my console, from the time I run the snippet. Not being controlled by mouseover.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm explaining and what the snippet is showing.

Comment: Ok so how can I have a function called only when the rect is moused -over? I have tried .on( "mouseover", function(d) { console.log("I am on it!"}) thanks

Comment: Check the answer again, I added another snippet with the code you should use.

Comment: I see your example works, but not my code with this.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you more than this. The problem here is very simple, and you can see (as you just said) that the code works. If it doesn't work for you (which is a mystery), you probably have **another** problem.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are calling the function at the time you are declaring it:

```
.on("mouseover", console.log("I am on it")) //function call
```

should be something like this:

```
.on("mouseover", console.log) //function ref
.on("mouseover", function(d) { console.log("I am on it") }) //function ref
```

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same result that the console logs the string before I do a mouseover.